# Sharing a SignalR hub between a WebApi and MVC project

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr, signalr-hub

Is there a recommended approach to sharing a SignalR hub across two applications?

The actual situation is a public facing WebAPI project and an internal MVC WebApp. What I'd like to do is call methods on a SignalR hub from the WebAPI project and have the results of these methods pushed to clients connected via the MVC app.

Would the best option be to create a third 'Hub' project and have both projects connect to that? If so, how are the hub instances managed? Can both applications get a reference to the same hub from distinct app pools (and possibly hosts)?

I read a little bit about `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext`, would this suffice to get a effectively a singleton hub which both apps could use?

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: signalR supports CORS at different domains , so you could use 1 app to serve both apps.p.s. +1 nice question.

Comment: Would that imply that it'd be best placed to extract the Hub into a separate app and let two others call it? This was my suspicion as I couldn't think of a nice way to place it in either one of the existing projects and have them call each other.

Comment: please have a look at this. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-in-signalr

Comment: Interesting stuff, we aim to deploy both the WebAPI and MVC app to Azure, but in the form of a VPN/VM with both sites running on the same VM. I'm not 100% sure whether this would count as a single server or not (would hope yes) so we may be able to avoid using a backplane approach, but would still need to share a hub across apps.

Comment: well  , I can tell you that in the next few hours/tomorrow you'll get more appropriate answer from the sR team members which has much more knowledge than I have :-) I will keep tracking this question cuz i'd like to hear best practices for that issue.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald did you have to implement the 'GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer()' in both apps? I have a question with a similar situation that I could use help on here http://stackoverflow.com/q/29932936/1211604

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just setup signalr message routing through a SQL Server table. It will automatically connect all hubs using the same routing setup. Nothing else to do, it's magic.

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["signalr"].ConnectionString);
```

You will need the following nuget package: Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SqlServer

Comment: Would there be a need to route via a SQL table if both apps reside on the same machine? One of our other devs is favouring just moving the signalr code to the webapi via a normal controller and letting the MVC project make a standard request to connect, establish the socket and send/recieve messages

Comment: same machine or same web application ? If they are in the same application, then you don't need the dependencyresolver, the hub will be one instance. Otherwise if they are in separate application pools or separate web applications, then you will need the dependencyresolver, SQL or any other.

Comment: They would be different apps, as per the question, one WebAPI and one MVC, but on the same machine, I presume that requires a dependency resolver

Comment: Yes. They won't be able to communicate as they don't share the same memory address space. They are isolated.

Comment: This is the solution we went for, one of our devs implemented the SQL backplane and we extracted the SignalR hub code into a seperate assembly shared by both MVC and WebAPI projects, works a treat....except on SQL Azure where it doesn't as it's unsupported :(

Comment: On Azure the pricing model for SQL is per transaction. You will pay a lot, won't you ?

Comment: I hear there is also a Redis backplane, it should be significantly faster. There's also the Azure service bus which might be better if your on Azure. Probably worth checking out. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-redis

Comment: There are lots of nosql like solutions out there. Optimization is a full time job.

Comment: @Softlion: where should I write this line? I've same issue. Could you please explain me in a brief? here is my question link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46730632/5743676