# Using SignalR in a Web Api Solution to send messages to Separate MVC Solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I have a .Net MVC web app that communicates to web services in a Web Api project. Both Projects are separate solutions and are on the same server but in separate App Pools. I have a situation where I need to use SignalR so that the Web Api project can publish a messages to specific users in the client web app in realtime.

After some searching I found that I may have to use a SQL backplane method in order to pass messages between two different solutions after I read this SO question 
[Sharing a SignalR hub between a WebApi and MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18704784/1211604)

I'm a little new to this idea and SignalR as well. Would I be able to put the Hub code inside of the Web Api project or would it need to go into it's own project and be hosted on the server as a seperate app pool as well?

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: You can definitely put the Hub in either the MVC or the Web Api project. SignalR libraries just need to be added. The back plane is a necessity if you have multiple servers serving requests to your users where some users may be on Server A and other on Server B. If you were to publish to all users, you would need the back plane.

Comment: What if the Web Api and Web App are on the same server but in different App pools and in different Solutions? @boosts

Comment: Why not keep the SingnalR Hubs in your API project and just Call your Api  Hubs from the MVC app?

Comment: I didn't think that was possible if the API and Web app were in separate projects and not under the same solution.  I just need the api to notify the hub that a process finished and then send that notification along with some data back to the Client.

Comment: I see your problem now. Yes, you will need to use the back plane approach.

Comment: @boosts ok, that's what I thought. I should still be fine with the hub being in the Web Api project though right?

Comment: That may work for your scenario. Depending on requirements in the future, you may need the type of implementation you suggested and also commented in the SO you found where you could add a separate project that is shared by both Web Api and MVC.