# How to broadcast events from Web Api project to MVC app on a different App Pool using SignalR

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, signalr

My windows server running IIS has an MVC application in one app pool and a Web Api project in another. These projects were developed in different solutions. The web app currently communicates with the Web Api to use as a rest service. I need to add a SignalR hub to the Web Api project so that it can broadcast some data to the web app in certain situations.

How can I go about doing this? I have read in other posts that you need to use Sql server as a backplane but I'm not sure that is necessary since the two apps are on the same server. If this is the case though, how does the Web app pick up the broadcast when the hub code is not in the project?

Comment: I haven't played with SignalR for a while but if you're apps aren't running in the same app pool (and therefore process) then you will need to implment the DependencyResolver. I'm don't think host matters much, in our final implementation we had WebAPI and MVC project on the same server but still went down the SQL backplane option

Comment: @dougajmcdonald I know you mentioned having to put the hub in a separate assembly. Once you guys did that did both apps just need to communicate with it like they normally would? Or was there something special that needed to be done? I understand if you don't actually remember.

Comment: is the webapi exposed to the outside world/ your intranet (i.e. called from a browser ajax call) or are you only calling it from the web app server side in your code behind/controllers etc?

Comment: It is exposed to the public. It's called from both AJAX in a web app as well as from a separate WPF app @Macb.

Comment: @Stavros_S okay, one last question. Are you using a single server or multiple? this will depend if you require a SQL Server backbone or not.

Comment: @Macb the MVC app and Web Api app are on a single Windows Server running IIS. But they are in separate app pools and were developed in separate solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are only using a single server, I would stay away from backbone scale out (i.e. SQL Server message bus, redis etc) until you are forced to scale out to multiple servers, in my experience SignalR scale out can be painful for multiple reasons.

Because you have the solutions in different app pools, you will need to think of one as the "SignalR Server" and the other as a "Client". I would pick the Web API as the server project and the web app as the client.

In order to communicate from the "Server" to the "Client" you should treat the web app as any other .net client (i.e. you can use a console app as a signalR client). At start up, or at some other event in your web app you will have to register with the "Server"(web api) that you are listening out for messages that signalR has to send. There is many great tutorials on this over at Asp.net, at the time of writing [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client) link explains how you could go about setting all this up, I have extreamly simplified this tutorial below:

1). install Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client from Nuget

2). register with the hub and start an async connection:

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://www.contoso.com/");
IHubProxy stockTickerHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("StockTickerHub");
stockTickerHubProxy.On<Stock>("UpdateStockPrice", stock => Console.WriteLine("Stock update for {0} new price {1}", stock.Symbol, stock.Price));
await hubConnection.Start();
```

Comment: So in the case here you are using the console app (or jweb app server code) to register a hub proxy, I'm assuming the same thing can be done from javascript from with in the web app right? One more question, the URL you pass into HubConnection is the URL of the Web Api, correct?

Comment: @Stavros_S Yes, easiest way to think about it. In the web api project there will be no need to do this - you shall have access to raise the event directly (again see tutorials on Asp.net/signalR). Yes, you can do the same from javascript straight to the web api, and yes the url you pass in will be the Hub URL, which will be on your web api project.

Comment: Thanks! I'll see how this works out. One last question, the server only needs to broadcast messages the client never needs to respond back in this specific case. Would you recommend PersistentConnection over a Hub?

Comment: @Stavros_S i would stick with the hub and let SigrnalR do the hard work for you, PersistentConnection is a little more manual.

Comment: so I tried this method but in javascript and I'm not establishing a connection to the hub. A detailed question can be seen here http://stackoverflow.com/q/29954672/1211604