# Failing to connect to a SignalR hub from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm trying to connect to a SignalR hub that is located in a seperate Web Api project from a MVC project but the connection keeps failing with error. I'm testing locally but apparently if you use IE it will handle Cross domain for you.

In Chrome

> http://localhost:53453/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22gweventhub%22%7D%5D&_=1430342757730
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

In IE

> Connection Error: Error during negotiation request.

Here is the server code for the hub.

```
[HubName("GWEventHub")]
public class GatewayEventHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        this.Groups.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId, this.Context.Request.User.Identity.Name);
        return (base.OnConnected());
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        this.Groups.Remove(this.Context.ConnectionId, this.Context.Request.User.Identity.Name);
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
}
```

Here is the Javascript attempting to connect to the hub. This is located in a separate MVC app.

```
$(function () {
    var connection = $.hubConnection('http://localhost:53453');
    connection.logging = true;

    var hub = connection.createHubProxy('GWEventHub');
    hub.logging = true;

    function handleMessage(message) {
        console.log('message from hub: ' + message);
    }

    hub.on('sendUserMessage', handleMessage);

    connection.start()
        .done(function() {
            alert('connect to GatewayEventHub, Connection ID = ' + connection.id);
        })
        .fail(function(e) {
            console.log('Connection Error ' + e);
        });
});
```

Is there something I'm missing in the connection process?

Answer (score 1):

Try by modifying your code to below

```js
$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:53453/signalr";
var hub = $.connection.GWEventHub;

//rest of your logging and other functions goes here
 
$.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
        alert('connect to GatewayEventHub, Connection ID = ' + $.connection.hub.id);
    })
    .fail(function(e) {
        console.log('Connection Error ' + e);
    });
```

Comment: so that seems to have gotten me a little closer but now the error is saying "Uncaught Error: SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/js'></script>." I tried adding <script src='/signalr/js'></script> to the view that is calling the signalr code but still no luck.

Comment: Could you try below?
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
Add tilde (~) in front of it.

Comment: unfortunately even after adding that I'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: if I run debug from Visual Studio a break occurs saying "JavaScript critical error at line 1, column 1 in http://localhost:63596/signalr/hubs\n\nSCRIPT1002: Syntax error"

Comment: It seems like your hub is not generating properly. Are you bundling that dynamic hub on BundleConfig? If so, please remove it from bundling and try again. Also try by directly calling the server hub like http://localhost:53453/signalr/hubs and see what's happening.

Comment: I have it outside of the bundles. localhost:53453 is the port for the web api project(separate solution) which has the actual signalr hub in it. localhost:63596 is the MVC project which has the client side js code in it. when navigating to /signalr/hubs from API project I get 404. In Mvc project it just redirects to a login view since there is technically no controller for action for that url.

Comment: Can you give access to signalr like <location path="signalr"><allow users="*" /></location>. Or if you have any authentication can you turn off it and try?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76591/discussion-between-stavros-s-and-ruchira).

Comment: Should I add this to the config of the web api project(which is where the signalr server side code is) or the MVC project (client side code) ?

Comment: The problem could be with the name of the hub: `GWEventHub` would translate to `gWEventHub` in javascript because hub names always start with a lower case letter. Since you spelled it incorrectly, you are getting a 404 error